# Serial Number (S/N) of device is different from what cordova serial is generating

Tags: android, cordova, serialization

I am having an issue with getting the correct serial number of an Android device. (SAMSUNG - T819Y).

The serial number (S/N) on the back of the device or sticker is different from what the **Cordova serial** is generating (Cordova-plugin-device). Not sure on what is the correct and unique serial number.

Or if ever, is there a way for me to get the serial number (on the back of the device) in a Cordova way?

Comment: Anyone help on this issue above? Thank you.